# Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, networking, ipv6

I have received the following rejection from Apple for my app the last couple of days. My app communicates with UDP and the remote server is always IPv4. I have used BSD sockets. Please guide me how can I solve this problem.

I have tried to create a NAT64 hotspot using an IPv4 network but I was unable to send any packets to the server. Moreover, we don't have IPv6 available at my place now.

From Apple:

> 2.2 Details
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an iPad running iOS 9.3.2 and iPhone running iOS 9.3.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> Specifically, during review we were unable to bypass the Initializing page. We encountered an error while waiting for the app to load. We've attached a screenshot for your reference.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise and resubmit your app for review.
>
> Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.
>
> For additional information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting iPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks.

Source Code Bellow:

UdpSocketManager.h >>

```
#ifndef UDP_SOCKET_MANAGER_H__
#define UDP_SOCKET_MANAGER_H__

#import "TInetAddr.h"

class UdpSocketManager
{
public:
    UdpSocketManager();
    ~UdpSocketManager();

    void getLocalAddress();
    void initializeSocket();
    void start();
    void stop();

    void sendSignal(int p_type, TInetAddr *p_destAddress, unsigned char *p_data, int p_length); 
    void receiveSignal();

    int localPort;    
    int signalingSocket;
    int signalSocketRecvLength;
    int socketFamily;

    int isIPV4Available;
    int isIPV6Available;

    char wifiIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char cellularIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    char wifiIP_v6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char cellularIP_v6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];    

    long returnLength;
    struct sockaddr_in remoteAddrForRecv;

    struct sockaddr_in  srcAddrV4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 srcAddrV6;    

    struct sockaddr_in  sendAddr4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 sendAddr6;

    bool running;
    pthread_t thread;
};

#endif
```

UdpSocketManager.m >>

```
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include "UdpSocketManager.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

unsigned int ipAddressToUnsignedInt(char *ipAddress)
{
    unsigned int ipAddressLongValue = 0L;
    int byteSegment = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(ipAddress); i++)
    {
        char ch = ipAddress[i];
        if(ch == '.')
        {
            ipAddressLongValue <<= 8;
            ipAddressLongValue |= byteSegment;
            byteSegment = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            byteSegment = byteSegment * 10 + (ch - 48);
        }
    }

    ipAddressLongValue <<= 8;
    ipAddressLongValue |= byteSegment;
    return ipAddressLongValue;
}

int custom_random(int max=65535)
{
    int randomValue;
    randomValue = arc4random_uniform(65535)%max;
    return randomValue;
}

int custom_random(int min, int max)
{
    int randomValue;
    randomValue = arc4random_uniform(max);
    if(randomValue<min)
        randomValue=(min+custom_random(max-min));
    return randomValue;
}



void* runUdpSocketManager(void *objRef)
{
    UdpSocketManager *THIS = (UdpSocketManager *) objRef;
    THIS->running=true;

    while (THIS->running) 
    {
        THIS->receiveSignal();
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}


UdpSocketManager::UdpSocketManager()
{
    socketFamily=AF_INET;
    signalingSocket=-1;
    running=false;
    initializeSocket();
}

UdpSocketManager::~UdpSocketManager()
{

}

void UdpSocketManager::getLocalAddress()
{
    //Read local address
    getLocalAddress();

    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success=0;

    isIPV4Available=FALSE;
    isIPV6Available=FALSE;
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);

    if (success == 0)
    {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL)
        {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET)
            {
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] hasPrefix:@"en"])
                {
                    isIPV4Available=TRUE;
                    strcpy(wifiIP, inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr));
                    printf("IP Address: %s\n",inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr));
                }
                else if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip0"])
                {
                    isIPV4Available=TRUE;
                    strcpy(cellularIP, inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr));
                    printf("IP Address: %s\n",inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr));
                }
            }
            else if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET6)
            {
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] hasPrefix:@"en"])
                {
                    isIPV6Available=TRUE;
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr), (char*)wifiIP_v6, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                    printf("Interface: %s IPV6: %s\n",temp_addr->ifa_name,wifiIP_v6);
                }
                else if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip0"])
                {
                    isIPV6Available=TRUE;
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr), (char*)cellularIP_v6, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                    printf("Interface: %s IPV6: %s\n",temp_addr->ifa_name,cellularIP_v6);
                }
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
}

void UdpSocketManager::initializeSocket()
{
    if(signalingSocket!=-1)
        close(signalingSocket);

    if (isIPV4Available)
    {
        if((signalingSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))==-1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to create signaling socket of AF_INET");
        }
        else
        {
            socketFamily=AF_INET;
            NSLog(@"Socket created successfully. [AF_INET]");
        }
    }
    else if(!isIPV4Available && isIPV6Available)
    {
        if((signalingSocket=socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))==-1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to create signaling socket of AF_INET6");
        }
        else
        {
            socketFamily=AF_INET6;
            NSLog(@"Socket created successfully. [AF_INET6]");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if((signalingSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))==-1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to create signaling socket of AF_INET");
        }
        else
        {
            socketFamily=AF_INET;
            NSLog(@"Socket created successfully. [AF_INET]");
        }
    }

    int count=0;
    while(true)
    {
        count++;
        if(socketFamily==AF_INET)
        {
            srcAddrV4.sin_len = sizeof(srcAddrV4);
            srcAddrV4.sin_family = socketFamily;
            srcAddrV4.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
            srcAddrV4.sin_port = htons(localPort);

            if (bind(signalingSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &srcAddrV4, sizeof(srcAddrV4)) < 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"[AF_INET] ERROR occured creating signaling port at attempt (%d) Port: %d", count, localPort);
                localPort=(int)custom_random(1024, 65535);
            }
            else
            {
                int on=1;
                setsockopt(signalingSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&on, sizeof(on));
                setsockopt(signalingSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));

                NSLog(@"[AF_INET] SignalingSocket Created Successfully at attempt (%d) Port: %d\n", count, localPort);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            srcAddrV6.sin6_len = sizeof(srcAddrV6);
            srcAddrV6.sin6_family = socketFamily;
            srcAddrV6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
            srcAddrV6.sin6_port = htons(localPort);

            if (bind(signalingSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &srcAddrV6, sizeof(srcAddrV6)) < 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"[AF_INET] ERROR occured creating signaling port at attempt (%d) Port: %d", count, localPort);
                localPort=(int)custom_random(1024, 65535);
            }
            else
            {
                int on=1;
                setsockopt(signalingSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&on, sizeof(on));
                setsockopt(signalingSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
                NSLog(@"[AF_INET6] SignalingSocket Created Successfully at attempt (%d) Port: %d\n", count, localPort);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void UdpSocketManager::start()
{
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, runUdpSocketManager, (void *) this);
}

void UdpSocketManager::stop()
{
    running=false;
}

void UdpSocketManager::receiveSignal()
{
    int port;
    char ipAddress[16];

    socklen_t fromlen;
    unsigned char udpSignalRecvBuffer[1600];

    fromlen = sizeof(remoteAddrForRecv);
    signalSocketRecvLength = (int)recvfrom(signalingSocket, (char *)udpSignalRecvBuffer,1600,0,(struct sockaddr *)&remoteAddrForRecv,&fromlen);

    if(signalSocketRecvLength>0)
    {
        strcpy(ipAddress, inet_ntoa(remoteAddrForRecv.sin_addr));
        port = ntohs(remoteAddrForRecv.sin_port);
        NSLog(@"RECEIVED %d bytes from %s:%d", signalSocketRecvLength, ipAddress, port);
    }
    else
    {
        usleep(10000);// 10 ms
    }
}


void UdpSocketManager::sendSignal(int p_type, TInetAddr *p_destAddress, unsigned char *p_data, int p_length)
{
    if(socketFamily==AF_INET6)
    {
        // Convert IPv4 address to IPv4-mapped-into-IPv6 address.        
        sendAddr6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        sendAddr6.sin6_port = p_destAddress->m_port;

        sendAddr6.sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr32[0] = 0;
        sendAddr6.sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr32[1] = 0;
        sendAddr6.sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr32[2] = htonl(0xffff);
        sendAddr6.sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr32[3] = ntohl(ipAddressToUnsignedInt(p_destAddress->m_address));

        sendAddr6.sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr16[4] = 0;
        sendAddr6.sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr16[5] = 0xffff;

        char ipV6Address[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &sendAddr6.sin6_addr, ipV6Address, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
        NSLog(@"ipV6Address: %s\n", ipV6Address);

        sendAddr6.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
        sendAddr6.sin6_scope_id = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        sendAddr4.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sendAddr4.sin_port   = htons(p_destAddress->m_port);

        if(inet_aton((char *) p_destAddress->m_address, &sendAddr4.sin_addr)==0)
        {
            NSLog(@"signal message - inet_aton() failed, %s", p_destAddress->m_address);
        }
    }


    if(socketFamily==AF_INET)
        returnLength=sendto(signalingSocket, p_data, p_length, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sendAddr4, sizeof(sendAddr4));
    else
        returnLength=sendto(signalingSocket, p_data, p_length, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sendAddr6, sizeof(sendAddr6));

    NSLog(@"SENT %ld bytes to %s:%d\n", returnLength,p_destAddress->m_address,p_destAddress->m_port);
}
```

Comment: "I have tried to create a hotspot NAT64 using a IPV4 network but i was unable to send any packets to server." Well that's the problem. It needs to work on a NAT64 environment before you submit it to the App Store.

Comment: When you send stuff on the socket, you need to give it an address structure. Where are you getting that address from?

Comment: iOS 9 only supports IPv6, not IPv4 at all, so your app MUST support IPv6 going forward. See [Supporting IPv6 in iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08282015a). When testing your app, you will need an IPv6 network that supports DNS64/NAT64 if you want to reach IPv4 networks.

Comment: You'll need to show your code before people can help you fix it

Comment: Uploaded code as well. please help me.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: This is wrong. Of course it supports IPv4.

Comment: @user102008: per the link I posted: "*At WWDC 2015 we announced that **iOS 9 will support IPv6-only network services**.*"

Comment: @user102008: also [this](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a): "*At WWDC 2015 we announced the transition to IPv6-only network services in iOS 9 ... If your app uses IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses, you will need to make some changes*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, and? I think you completely misunderstand what "support IPv6-only network services" means. You have to read the basic documentation again. That's like saying, this restaurant is accessible to wheelchair-bound people means that it does not support people who walk.

Comment: My codes are ok or not?

Comment: You've indicated you don't have access to an IPv6 network to test this, Maverick. I think that's the first thing you need to fix - you can't guess at a solution and resubmit it to Apple in the hope that it works. What happens if you introduce a bug?

Comment: @user102008: may I politely ask you to tone down the sharpness of your remarks? Be nice, remember! This is not my domain space at all, but IPv6-only seems very clear to me, in plain English terms: a restaurant that is wheelchair-only would be a better parallel. If you are sure that Remy is incorrect, can you explain to him/her in a different way?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, when Apple said that "_iOS 9 will support **IPv6-only** network services_," it didn't mean "_iOS 9 will **only** support IPv6 network services_." The Apple requirement is that any application in its store will work on an IPv6-only network, too, not exclusively.

Comment: @halfer: "You've indicated you don't have access to an IPv6 network to test this, Maverick." The OP said "I have tried to create a NAT64 hotspot using an IPv4 network". That *is* the IPv6-only network environment they need to test.

Comment: @halfer: There was no "sharpness". Everything I said was true and relevant. The restaurant (iOS 9) does support people who only walk (IPv4-only networks), people who both walk and use a wheelchair (networks with both IPv4 and IPv6), and people who can only use a wheelchair (IPv6-only network). In fact, most people in the world can only walk (most networks in the world are IPv4-only networks). Previous versions of iOS did not support connecting to IPv4 resources on IPv6-only networks, but iOS 9 does.

Comment: We can agree to disagree on the sharpness, @user102008 - that's an honest third-party assessment, intended to be helpful feedback. On the topic at hand, your and Ron's comments clear away my confusion, so thanks. IPv6 only does mean what it sounds like in plain English, but Apple did not mean that other network types are not supported. I thought that the word "only" had been redefined! `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your "Convert IPv4 address to IPv4-mapped-into-IPv6 address" is correct. Rather than trying to construct an address yourself, you should call `getaddrinfo()` with a string of the thing you want to connect to (which could be either a hostname or an IPv4 address literal), and it will return to you a list of `sockaddr`s; you should use the first one from there to pass to `sendto`. It will give you the appropriate IP address family to use, and if you give an IPv4 address and it is an IPv6-only network (without you having to test anything), it will automatically give you the correct IPv6 address to use for that NAT64 router (without you needing to figure this out yourself). (If you wanted to manually construct an IPv6 address from IPv4 using NAT64/DNS64 without using `getaddrinfo()`, you would have to follow the complicated procedure in [RFC 7050](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7050).)

Also, all the things you are doing in `getLocalAddress()` is unnecessary and potentially leads to more problems. You don't need `isIPV4Available` or `isIPV6Available` -- you shouldn't care at that point. Just create and bind *both* an IPv4 and an IPv6 socket in the beginning (not needing to care which one works), and each time you need to send, you get the right `sockaddr` to use using `getaddrinfo()` as above, and then send to the socket whose address family corresponds to the `sockaddr` you are using. And when you want to receive, you call `recvfrom` on both sockets.

Comment: I have done exactly what you advised here, but this way didn't able to send UDP packets to server.

Comment: @MaverickKing: And what error did you get? If you are using IPv4 literals with a numeric port number, you could be running into [this bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47312) where `getaddrinfo()` erroneously returns ports of 0 and you need to manually set your port back afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems with the code you have shown:

1. `UdpSocketManager` does not call `getLocalAddress()` before calling  `initializeSocket()`, so the binding socket is always IPv4, never IPv6. You are also not initializing `localPort` before calling `initializeSocket()`, either.
2. `getLocalAddress()` (if ever called) calls itself, so you have an endless recursion loop.
3. The use of `custom_random()` in a loop to pick a random binding port is just plain wrong, unnecessary, and potentially unending.  To pick a random port when your configured port fails, just call `bind()` *one time* with the port set to 0. The OS knows which ports are available and will pick an available random port for you.  Your entire `initializeSocket()` is overly complicated for what it attempts to do. It can be greatly simplified.
4. When enabling `SO_REUSEADDR`, it must be enabled *before* calling `bind()`, not after. Also look at `SO_REUSEPORT`.
5. Your `remoteAddrForRecv` variable is declared as `sockaddr_in`, which is only large enough to hold an IPv4 address and will cause `recvfrom()` to fail if called on an IPv6 socket. Use `sockaddr_storage` instead.  In fact. All of your `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6` variables should be replaced with `sockaddr_storage`.
6. `inet_ntoa()` is likewise also IPv4-only. Use `inet_ntop()` instead to handle both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Try something more like this instead:

UdpSocketManager.h

```
#ifndef UDP_SOCKET_MANAGER_H__
#define UDP_SOCKET_MANAGER_H__

#import "TInetAddr.h"

class UdpSocketManager
{
public:
    UdpSocketManager();
    ~UdpSocketManager();

    void getLocalAddresses();
    void initializeSocket();
    void start();
    void stop();

    void sendSignal(int p_type, TInetAddr *p_destAddress, unsigned char *p_data, int p_length);    
    void receiveSignal();

    int localPort;    
    int signalingSocket;
    int socketFamily;

    int isIPV4Available;
    int isIPV6Available;

    char wifiIP_v4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char cellularIP_v4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    char wifiIP_v6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char cellularIP_v6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];    

    bool running;
    pthread_t thread;
};

#endif
```

UdpSocketManager.m

```
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include "UdpSocketManager.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void* runUdpSocketManager(void *objRef)
{
    UdpSocketManager *THIS = (UdpSocketManager *) objRef;

    while (THIS->running) 
    {
        THIS->receiveSignal();
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

UdpSocketManager::UdpSocketManager()
{
    socketFamily = AF_INET;
    signalingSocket = -1;
    localPort = 0; // or whatever port you actual want
    srcAddrLen = 0;
    sendAddrLen = 0;
    running = false;
    initializeSocket();
}

UdpSocketManager::~UdpSocketManager()
{
    if(signalingSocket != -1)
    {
        close(signalingSocket);
        signalingSocket = -1;
    }
}

void UdpSocketManager::getLocalAddresses()
{
    //Read local addresses

    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;

    isIPV4Available = FALSE;
    isIPV6Available = FALSE;

    memset(&wifiIP_v4, 0, sizeof(wifiIP_v4));
    memset(&cellularIP_v4, 0, sizeof(cellularIP_v4));

    memset(&wifiIP_v6, 0, sizeof(wifiIP_v6));
    memset(&cellularIP_v6, 0, sizeof(cellularIP_v6));

    if(getifaddrs(&interfaces) == 0)
    {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL)
        {
            if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] hasPrefix:@"en"])
            {
                if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    isIPV4Available = TRUE;
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr), wifiIP_v4, sizeof(wifiIP_v4));
                    printf("Interface: %s IPv4: %s\n", temp_addr->ifa_name, wifiIP_v4);
                }
                else if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    isIPV6Available = TRUE;
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr), wifiIP_v6, sizeof(wifiIP_v6));
                    printf("Interface: %s IPv6: %s\n", temp_addr->ifa_name, wifiIP_v6);
                }
            }
            else if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip0"])
            {
                if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    isIPV4Available = TRUE;
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr), cellularIP_v4, sizeof(cellularIP_v4));
                    printf("Interface: %s IPv6: %s\n", temp_addr->ifa_name, cellularIP_v4);
                }
                else if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    isIPV6Available = TRUE;
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr), cellularIP_v6, sizeof(cellularIP_v6));
                    printf("Interface: %s IPv6: %s\n", temp_addr->ifa_name, cellularIP_v6);
                }
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }

        freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    }
}

void UdpSocketManager::initializeSocket()
{
    struct sockaddr_storage srcAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *srcAddr6;
    struct sockaddr_in *srcAddr4;
    socklen_t srcAddrLen;

    if(signalingSocket != -1)
    {
        close(signalingSocket);
        signalingSocket = -1;
    }

    getLocalAddresses();

    if(isIPV6Available)
    {
        signalingSocket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if(signalingSocket == -1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to create IPv6 signaling socket");
            return;
        }

        socketFamily = AF_INET6;
        NSLog(@"IPv6 Socket created successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        signalingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if(signalingSocket == -1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to create IPv4 signaling socket");
            return;
        }

        socketFamily = AF_INET;
        NSLog(@"IPv4 Socket created successfully");
    }

    int on = 1;
    setsockopt(signalingSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &on, sizeof(on));
    setsockopt(signalingSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));

    if(socketFamily == AF_INET6)
    {
        on = 0;
        setsockopt(signalingSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &on, sizeof(on));

        srcAddr6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) &srcAddr;
        srcAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);

        srcAddr6->sin6_len = srcAddrLen;
        srcAddr6->sin6_family = socketFamily;
        srcAddr6->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
        srcAddr6->sin6_port = htons(localPort);
    }
    else
    {
        srcAddr4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) &srcAddr;
        srcAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

        srcAddr4->sin_len = srcAddrLen;
        srcAddr4->sin_family = socketFamily;
        srcAddr4->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        srcAddr4->sin_port = htons(localPort);
    }

    if (bind(signalingSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &srcAddr, srcAddrLen) < 0)
    {
        if (localPort == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR occured binding random signaling port");
            close(signalingSocket);
            signalingSocket = -1;
            return;
        }

        NSLog(@"ERROR occured binding signaling port: %d", localPort);

        if(socketFamily == AF_INET6)
            srcAddr6->sin6_port = 0;
        else
            srcAddr4->sin_port = 0;

        if (bind(signalingSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &srcAddr, srcAddrLen) < 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR occured binding random signaling port");
            close(signalingSocket);
            signalingSocket = -1;
            return;
        }

        getsockname(signalingSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &srcAddr, &srcAddrLen);

        if(socketFamily == AF_INET6)
            localPort = ntohs(srcAddr6->sin6_port);
        else
            localPort = ntohs(srcAddr4->sin_port);
    }

    NSLog(@"SignalingSocket bound successfully on Port: %d\n", localPort);
}

void UdpSocketManager::start()
{
    if(signalingSocket != -1)
    {
        running = true;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, runUdpSocketManager, this);
    }
}

void UdpSocketManager::stop()
{
    running = false;
}

void UdpSocketManager::receiveSignal()
{
    int port;
    char ipAddress[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    unsigned char udpSignalRecvBuffer[1600];
    ssize_t signalRecvLength;

    struct sockaddr_storage remoteAddr;
    socklen_t fromlen;

    fromlen = sizeof(remoteAddr);
    signalRecvLength = recvfrom(signalingSocket, udpSignalRecvBuffer, sizeof(udpSignalRecvBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &remoteAddr, &fromlen);

    if(signalRecvLength >= 0)
    {
        if(remoteAddrForRecv.ss_family == AF_INET6)
        {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *remoteAddr6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) &remoteAddr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(remoteAddr6->sin6_addr), ipAddress, sizeof(ipAddress));
            port = ntohs(remoteAddr6->sin6_port);
        }
        else
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *remoteAddr4 = (struct sockaddr_in4 *) &remoteAddr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(remoteAddr4->sin_addr), ipAddress, sizeof(ipAddress));
            port = ntohs(remoteAddr4->sin_port);
        }

        NSLog(@"RECEIVED %d bytes from %s:%d", signalRecvLength, ipAddress, port);
    }
    else
    {
        usleep(10000);// 10 ms
    }
}


void UdpSocketManager::sendSignal(int p_type, TInetAddr *p_destAddress, unsigned char *p_data, int p_length)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage sendAddr;
    socklen_t sendAddrLen;

    ssize_t returnLength;

    char ipAddress[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if(socketFamily == AF_INET6)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *sendAddr6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) &sendAddr;
        sendAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);

        sendAddr6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        sendAddr6->sin6_port = htons(p_destAddress->m_port);

        // Convert IPv4 address to IPv4-mapped IPv6 address.        
        sendAddr6->sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr32[0] = 0;
        sendAddr6->sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr32[1] = 0;
        sendAddr6->sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr16[4] = 0;
        sendAddr6->sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr16[5] = 0xffff;
        sendAddr6->sin6_addr.__u6_addr.__u6_addr32[3] = inet_addr(p_destAddress->m_address);            

        sendAddr6->sin6_flowinfo = 0;
        sendAddr6->sin6_scope_id = 0;

        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(sendAddr6->sin6_addr), ipAddress, sizeof(ipAddress));
    }
    else
    {
        struct sockaddr_in *sendAddr4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) &sendAddr;
        sendAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

        sendAddr4->sin_family = AF_INET;
        sendAddr4->sin_port = htons(p_destAddress->m_port);

        if(inet_aton((char *) p_destAddress->m_address, &(sendAddr4->sin_addr)) == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"signal message - inet_aton() failed, %s", p_destAddress->m_address);
            return;
        }

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sendAddr4->sin_addr), ipAddress, sizeof(ipAddress));
    }

    returnLength = sendto(signalingSocket, p_data, p_length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sendAddr, sendAddrLen);
    if(returnLength >= 0)
        NSLog(@"SENT %ld bytes to %s:%d\n", returnLength, ipAddress, p_destAddress->m_port);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for AFNetworking for reachability in IPv6 and IPv4**

change the following code in class **AFNetworkReachabilityManager**

```
 + (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static AFNetworkReachabilityManager *_sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        struct sockaddr_in6 address;
        bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
        address.sin6_len = sizeof(address);
        address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        _sharedManager = [self managerForAddress:&address];
    });
    return _sharedManager;
}
```